# binarise outliers in R

Tags: r

if my df comprises of:

Example,

```
Var1   Var2 
0.11   11
0.12   12
0.13   13
0.14   14
8.99   15
0.11   999
```

and I've use the outlier detection function I found on other posts to detect outliers following the criteria in the function.

```
is_outlier <- function(df, na.rm = FALSE) {
  qs = quantile(df, probs = c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm)
  
  lowerq <- qs[1]
  upperq <- qs[2]
  iqr = upperq - lowerq 
  
  extreme.threshold.upper = (iqr * 3) + upperq
  extreme.threshold.lower = lowerq - (iqr * 3)
  
  # Return logical vector
  df > extreme.threshold.upper | df < extreme.threshold.lower
}
```

How do I know get R to create a new column to provide binary output with outliers as below? I'm hoping to treat Var1 and Var2 by binarising each variable independently.

```
Var1   Var2 OutVar1 OutVar2
0.11   11   0       0
0.12   12   0       0
0.13   13   0       0
0.14   14   0       0
8.99   15   1       0
0.11   999  0       1
```

Would it be a quick fix if I would instead treat each row as a single observation. In this case, I'm hoping to see 1 for row 4 and row 5 with a single new column created only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function currently returns a logical vector. To get binary output convert it to integer.

```
is_outlier <- function(df, na.rm = FALSE) {
  qs = quantile(df, probs = c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm)
  
  lowerq <- qs[1]
  upperq <- qs[2]
  iqr = upperq - lowerq 
  
  extreme.threshold.upper = (iqr * 3) + upperq
  extreme.threshold.lower = lowerq - (iqr * 3)
  
  as.integer(df > extreme.threshold.upper | df < extreme.threshold.lower)
}
```

Use `lapply` to apply this function to all columns.

```
df[paste0('Out', names(df))] <- lapply(df, is_outlier)
df

#  Var1 Var2 OutVar1 OutVar2
#1 0.11   11       0       0
#2 0.12   12       0       0
#3 0.13   13       0       0
#4 0.14   14       0       0
#5 8.99   15       1       0
#6 0.11  999       0       1
```

You can also use `across` in `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% mutate(across(.fns = is_outlier, .names = 'out{col}'))
```

Comment: Thank you Ronak. How different would the code be if say use Var1 as determinant only?

Comment: Do you want to create only 1 output column? In which case you can keep your original function and use `df$OutVar <- as.integer(Reduce(\`|\`, lapply(df, is_outlier)))`

Comment: Hi Ronak, as a follow up, say if i only want the outlier function applied to Var1, would the modification be ```is_outlier <- function(df$Var1, na.rm = FALSE)```?

Comment: Don't change the `is_outlier` function. You can do `df$new_col <- is_outlier(df$Var1)`

Comment: Thanks Ronak, I've noticed if I were to then combine the original df using ```df$new_col <- c(df, is_outlier(df$Var1))```the length becomes different. on their own they have the same length of 6 but if i start joining them, they length becomes longer.

Answer (score 1):

We may do this with `+` to convert to integer

```
is_outlier <- function(df, na.rm = FALSE) {
  qs = quantile(df, probs = c(0.25, 0.75), na.rm = na.rm)
  
  lowerq <- qs[1]
  upperq <- qs[2]
  iqr = upperq - lowerq 
  
  extreme.threshold.upper = (iqr * 3) + upperq
  extreme.threshold.lower = lowerq - (iqr * 3)
  
   +(df > extreme.threshold.upper | df < extreme.threshold.lower)
}
```

Then, we do this as

```
df[paste0('Out', names(df))] <- lapply(df, is_outlier)
```